# Cheapest transport (other than walking) from ACY to touristy area in Atlantic City

Tags: public-transport, budget, transportation

I might have a 7 hour layover in ACY. In which case, I might as well travel over to check out Atlantic City. What is the cheapest mode of transport from ACY to the touristy area in Atlantic City?

The [Wikitravel page](http://wikitravel.org/en/Atlantic_City) says that it's uncommon to go from ACY (it being a small airport) to Atlantic City and most travelers go from Philadelphia.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion would be the Atlantic City jitney

http://jitneyac.com/index.php

Current cost is $10 to $15 dollars each way.    They also do an in city service for $2.25.

You could also look at the free shuttle to Egg Harbour rail station

http://www.sjta.com/sjta/pdfs/Egg_Harbor_AC_Airport_Brochure.pdf

Which also connects to a couple of Nj transit bus routes
However times are quite limited incomparison to the jitney service

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Rail service to Atlantic City has been suspended until mid 2019 for repairs and upgrades.
The Jitney seems to run infrequently, if it is not running on arrival, a taxi at the airport will charge $27 plus $1 each additional passenger from Atlantic City Airport to anywhere in Atlantic City. An Atlantic City taxi will charge the same price for a return to the airport.